# VSTO for Outlook - Floating Window Mind Boggling Bug

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2010

The code for this add in is available [here](http://www.nikgupta.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/POC.zip). The videos demonstrating the behaviours are listed in the body of this explanation. Here are the two links for convenience
[Bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTUujwng_cY)
[WorkAround](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6a0xvBKGSE)

I have been trying to write an Add In for Outlook 2010 and 2013 using Visual Studio 2013 however I have run into a very weird bug. These are the steps to reproduce this mind boggling bug which happens when the add in is installed in Outlook. The platform is Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 Enterprise

1. Double click an email and opens it up in a new window (inspector
   window)
2. In the TaskBar of Windows you would now notice a layered
   icon for Outlook. On mouseover Windows would show you the main
   outlook window and the opened up email (rendered in Aero theme if
   enabled)
3. Simply go back and close the maximised email.
4. Windows TaskBar still shows two layered icons as above but now if you mouse over
   the email window it shows nothing. It is like a ghost thing which
   isn't cleaned up.

The best way I could demonstrate this was by recording a small video which is available [here](http://youtu.be/bTUujwng_cY)

This however is not the end of story. It gets better and interesting. Now do this.

1. Restart Outlook
2. Maximise an email again as earlier.
3. Mouse over the icon in the task bar to bring over the two layered window thing. You can close the maximised window from here too. Go ahead and do that.
4. This time as you can see the window for the email is properly gone! The task bar is now showing a single icon for Outlook.

To illustrate this behaviour I recorded another video which is available [here](http://youtu.be/M6a0xvBKGSE).

A few points to note about this behaviour

1. This happens only on Outlook 2010. With Outlook 2013 this behaviour does not show up.
2. I have narrowed this down to one line of code. In the OutlookExplorerWrapper if the following line is commented the behaviour disappears from Outlook 2010

   var s = mail.Body;

Essentially simply accessing the Body property on the MailItem object leads to this behaviour. I have swapped Body with RTFBody which again makes the bug disappear.

I am truly at my wits end here. Any help is much much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I took a look at the sample project and didn't notice any statements for releasing underlying COM objects. Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28office.12%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

You need to release underlying COM objects in the code instantly.

Comment: The code is littered with the right calls to let go of COM objects. I have even wrapped it up as extension methods so it is easier to use the Marshal class for releasing COM resources. Besides as I pointed out in my original post the bug is coming down to one line of code. This generic kind of statement does not really help.